# Codeigniter PHP MySQL deployment to Heroku not loading

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, deployment, server

I used codeigniter to code my project and it works on localhost using MAMP, however, it doesn't work when I try deploying it to Heroku. It is giving me an internal server error (500)

I'm using an RDS instance from AWS for my database..

Any help please.. here's the URL: https://calm-harbor-2745.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This question is very hard to answer without having magic powers since you're not providing any information other than that it's a 500 server error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what `heroku logs` says?

If you're using the `mysql` extension and not PDO or something, have you enabled it via `composer.json`? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

Comment: Codeigniter's default `mysql` is deprecated since PHP 5.5.   In your CodeIgniter database config file you can change the dbdriver to mysqli, which is supported by default on the versions of PHP on heroku: `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`